# How is this google analytics script different than what google gives?

Tags: cookies, google-analytics

I saw this google analytics script suck illegal websites online can someone tell me what this script exactly do?

[image: Phtoto]

Answer (score 0):

So essentially the extra pieces of code there are two extra conditions.

1. Checks if the user agent (browser) doesn't contain 'android', 'iphone', 'ipad', 'ps4', 'playstation'. This is the first condition. If this condition is not true, then the 2nd condition will not need to be evaluated.
2. checks if the "showed ad" cookie is equal to the string "yes". If this is true, then it will register a pageview in the GA property.

summary: It looks like the code is just trying to exclude android, iphone, ipad, ps4, playstation devices and as well as exclude users who haven't seen the ad.

Really weird as it doesn't stop the user from accessing the page, just stops you from seeing the data in GA.